# Pyspark -- AWS EMR: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage -- Failed to connect to ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, amazon-emr

I have a monthly data pipeline on AWS EMR that used to run fine. This previous run, we received a much higher load of data than usual. Now when I submit a job I start hitting weird errors and HDFS gets corrupted as well.

Error:

```
An error occurred while calling o688.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 183 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal/XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:554)
```

Once this error occurs, I check the status of my cluster

```
hdfs fsck /
```

and see

```
Total size:    15157892117 B (Total open files size: 135183786 B)
 Total dirs:    64
 Total files:   1787
 Total symlinks:                0 (Files currently being written: 3)
 Total blocks (validated):      1847 (avg. block size 8206763 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 4)
  ********************************
  UNDER MIN REPL'D BLOCKS:      193 (10.449377 %)
  dfs.namenode.replication.min: 1
  CORRUPT FILES:        177
  MISSING BLOCKS:       193
  MISSING SIZE:         5932451768 B
  CORRUPT BLOCKS:       193
  ********************************
 Minimally replicated blocks:   1654 (89.55062 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       1413 (76.50243 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    1
 Average block replication:     1.6605306
 Corrupt blocks:                193
 Missing replicas:              1413 (30.237535 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          2
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Mon Oct 05 23:54:14 UTC 2020 in 21 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/' is CORRUPT
```

Also, I used to be able to run the pipeline with less than 15 task nodes, but had to up it to 45 task nodes in order to avoid `Out Of Memory` errors, until I hit this error.

Any thoughts on what might be going on and why it keeps failing?

Comment: I encountered the same errors...
do you have any solution?